# How to construct an url to point to an app in ios appstore?

Tags: android, webview, itunes

I have an Android App and I would like to open a View to show the users, that the same App is also available in the IOS World.
I thought doing this by providing an URL in a Webview and pointing to the AppStores Site of my App.

Now I am stock constructing such an URL. The only way to get such an URL was for me to copy the link behind a button in the ITunes Client Application of my App. THe URL looks like this :
https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app//?mt=8

I guess the  Part will change with updating my app. So I am sure, this is not the right way doing this.

I also did not find the App with searching in a browser. Stupidingly it looks like we can only search for apps with apple's official clients.

Can someone help me how to get the URL to an App correctly ? Or does someone know an alternativ way to achieve my usecase ?